# Network printer won't print from Notepad

Tags: network-printer, raspberry-pi, cups

I have a network printer (using a Raspberry Pi as a server with CUPS and SANE), I can print fine from any computer to the printer but it will not print anything from Notepad, what is the cause of this?

Comment: Can you print from any other program on Windows (the browser, Wordpad, etc.) on that same computer?  They should all be using the same printer driver as on Notepad.  Make sure Notepad is set to print to the right place tool

Comment: I can print from any other program, Chrome, Word, etc

Comment: Can it print to a file?

Comment: The file does not seem to be saved anywhere, I am not prompted for a save location so I assume it would be normally saved in Documents